# File placement and Build type for SVG's in Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

I had a question concerning the documentation for Xamarin.Native SVG support [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support#xamarinandroid):

In the sample code it calls `LoadFile`:

```
ImageService.Instance
    .LoadFile("image.svg")
    .
    .
```

In order for this to work, where in the project must image.svg be placed?
And what is the Build Type for image.svg (Content, AndroidRersource, etc.)?
And is it the same behavior for iOS?

I'm having trouble getting it to work. I placed my svg in the drawable directory with a build type of `AndroidResource`.

```
Android Project
    |
    |
    -> Resources
        |
        |
        -> drawable
            |
            |
            -> image.svg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageService.Instance.LoadFile`: It used for loading files from the disk (full path only).

You should use `LoadFileFromApplicationBundle`(application bundle), OR `LoadCompiledResource`(application resource).

**Load an image from a file from application bundle.**

```
          /// <summary>
          /// Load an image from a file from application bundle.
          /// eg. assets on Android, compiled resource for other platforms
          /// </summary>
          /// <returns>The new TaskParameter.</returns>
          /// <param name="filepath">Path to the file.</param>
          TaskParameter LoadFileFromApplicationBundle(string filepath);
```

Xamarin.Android

xml:

```
  <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Assets: with AndroidAsset of Build Action

[image]

MainActivity:

```
 var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
        var filePath = "sample2.svg";
        ImageService.Instance.LoadFileFromApplicationBundle(filePath).WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(64, 0, true)).Into(imageView);
```

**Load an image from a file from application resource.** Use the name of the resource in drawable folder without extension.

```
          /// <summary>
          /// Load an image from a file from application resource.
          /// </summary>
          /// <returns>The new TaskParameter.</returns>
          /// <param name="resourceName">Name of the resource in drawable folder without extension</param>
          TaskParameter LoadCompiledResource(string resourceName);
```

Xamarin.Android

xml:

```
 <FFImageLoading.Views.ImageViewAsync
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Drawable Resource: with AndroidResource of BuildAction

[image]

MainActivity:

```
var filePath = "sample";

ImageService.Instance.LoadCompiledResource(filePath).WithCustomDataResolver(new SvgDataResolver(64, 0, true)).Into(imageView);
```

[image]

In the link you provided, it also shows the way to load from embedded resources on Xamarin.Forms, you could check it. https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki/SVG-support#xamarinandroid

Comment: LoadCompiledResource did the trick! For iOS, I added my svg as a BundleResource in the Resources directory. For Android, I added my svg as an AndroidAsset in the Assets folder.